# How to avoid generation of NA's during creation of a data frame

Tags: r

I have some data files and from these files I generate data data frame say as below:

```
                                           V1 V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7
1                                          bb  A <NA> <NA>    P <NA>    M
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  M <NA>   A  <NA> <NA>    P
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5                                paired box 8  P    P    P <NA>    P <NA>
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P <NA> <NA>    P <NA>    P
```

During the generation of data frame onwards `V3`, it creates `NA's` which I don't want to generate. I Know I can remove them by `data[!is.na(data)]` but I want to have a control. I want to know is there any way to do this.

The second thing is I Want to sort the rows without first column `(V1)` in the order of `P , A , M` . I know I can order them by ascending or descending order but I want the above said order pattern. How to do it. Thanks in advance.

Edited: Expected output

```
                                           V1 V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7
1                                          bb  P    A    M  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P    A    M  <NA> <NA>  <NA>   
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
5                                paired box 8  P    P    P    P  <NA>  <NA>
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P    P    P  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
```

Example : On the first iteration i get like this

```
                                           V1 V2    
1                                          bb  P     
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P   
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P        
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A   
5                                paired box 8  P     
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P     
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P
```

Now when the entry for say gene `bb` comes like below

```
                                           V1 V2  V3  
1                                          bb  P   A  
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P   
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P       
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A   
5                                paired box 8  P   
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P   
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P
```

Then automatically the other entries of colum V3 changes to `<NA>`, keeping no room in that column for other elements say below:

```
                                           V1 V2  V3  
1                                          bb  P   A  
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P  <NA> 
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P  <NA>      
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A  <NA> 
5                                paired box 8  P  <NA>   
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P  <NA>   
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P  <NA>
```

Then when the new element comes , it finds no place in column `V3`, then it creates a new column to put the new enteries

```
                                           V1 V2  V3  V4
1                                          bb  P   A  M
2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P  <NA> 
3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P  <NA>      
4        heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')  A  <NA> 
5                                paired box 8  P  <NA>   
6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P  <NA>   
7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P  <NA>
```

Comment: I think you are sharing with some incorrect format.  No, I get the same file with extension `.lnk`

Comment: @akrun ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/f69c46mdnrvrxui/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: this is 2nd file ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sezeybl36i3u85/gpl1.csv?dl=0

Comment: The first file looks okay.  Why do you want me to look the 2nd file

Comment: My code maps each entry of column 1 of test file with column 1 of gpl file to get the gene name. It generated the new data fram df1 by the gene name from gpl file and call values say `(P,M,A)` from test file

Comment: The data in the two files looks different than the one you showed in the example.  Is it a new question?

Comment: To me, this looks like a new question.  Please do post as a separate question as this is already getting crowded with comments.

Comment: @akrun ... its a sample data of the same question. May b i have shared other file, but the pattern is same. U can see some duplicate entries in test file and obviously the gene name will appear more than once from gpl file.  In order to remove the duplicates, i create a data frame to displace the gene name only once with its all corresponding detection calls (P or A or M).

Comment: In the first file, there is only a single column with `P A M` and in the second one there is not any.  Also, your question is now to map between the two files based on a single column, which I think is different from your original question.

Comment: I need to excuse myself, this problem is generation of NAs nothing else as i have posted above. In summary i don't want to generated the NAs  with the generation of data frame if the place is empty.  Thanks very much for your valuable time.

Comment: May be you are right, but from the datasets you shared, the example showed, and now about the problem with the mapping, it is all confusing.

Comment: @akrun .. Yeah that is right, The data is very large with millions of rows and I have put data with a few rows.  I think I need to ask the question with more explanation and example that I missed here.  Hope will get back with a new question regarding control of NA's. Once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the part about getting `NA` for elements if the elements are empty by using `read.csv`.  If I specify `na.strings=''`, the elements will be `NA`.  Use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop through the rows, convert the row elements to factor and specify levels in the order `P`, `A`, `M`.  If there is lagging/leading spaces, remove it using `gsub` before converting to "factor", sort, transpose and assign the results to the selected columns `df1[-1] <- t(apply(...)`

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) 
   sort(factor(gsub('^ +| +$', '', x), levels=c('P', 'A', 'M', '')))))
 df1
 #                                           V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 #1                                          bb  P  A  M         
 #2              chemokine (C-C motif) ligand 5  P               
 #3 discoidin domain receptor tyrosine kinase 1  P  A  M         
 #4       heat shock 70kDa protein 6 (HSP70B')   A               
 #5                                paired box 8  P  P  P  P      
 #6 replication factor C (activator 1) 2, 40kDa  P               
 #7 ubiquitin-like modifier activating enzyme 7  P  P  P
```